# Android - Creating LinearLayout with 3 children in the screen at all time

Tags: android, android-layout

Basically I'm trying to create a chat app with this kind of layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <!-- Avatar -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/message_other_text_avatar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/avatarBackgroundSize"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/avatarBackgroundSize"
        android:background="@drawable/background_white_radius6"
        android:contentDescription="@string/avatar"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar_rounded_default" />

    <!--Text-->
    <com.test.www.classes.CustTV
        android:id="@+id/message_other_text_messageText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/bubblechat_left_blue"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/messagePlaceholder"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorBlack"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
        app:fontFace="@string/opensans_regular" />

    <com.test.www.classes.CustTV
        android:id="@+id/message_other_txt_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="@string/numberPlaceholder"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/miBlack"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_smaller"
        app:fontFace="@string/opensans_regular" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Problem is, that last `TextView` for time always gets pushed off screen if the content of the message gets long (as long as the space left after taken by the `ImageView`). How to keep the time `TextView` to stay visible to user?

EDIT :

Here's the chat layout

[image: Chat]

The one circled by green is the one which I want to get, it is quite easy to get that though because there are only 2 children and `LinearLayout` keeps it inside the group, whereas the one circled by red has its children pushed out of the screen. It's different in preview mode though, here's how it looks like in preview mode

[image: Preview]

Comment: post your actual design with problematic desing

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [LinearLayout Weight property](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight). 
You could do something like:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:weightSum="1"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

  <!-- Avatar -->
  <ImageView
    android:width:="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2" />

  <!--Text-->
  <com.test.www.classes.CustTV
    android:width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.6" />

  <!--Time-->
  <com.test.www.classes.CustTV
    android:width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This should lead to a layout which has the 3 Objects Avatar, Text and Time with Avatar and Time having a width of 0.2 times the screen Width, and Text having a width of 0.6 times the screen width.

**Please note** that this is not a working example, e.g. `android:height` properties are missing. But I think it explains what I want to suggest. Also note that you need to set `android:width:="0dp"` when using `android:layout_weight`.

Comment: It works, yes, but for my requirement, the width of the one in the center to be dynamic..

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution which involves wrapping the `TextViews` in a `RelativeLayout`. And the problem actually lies with `TextView`'s growing text, so I had to adjust the alignments accordingly. Didn't realize it sooner, silly me.

Here's the code :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="left">

    <!--Text-->
    <com.test.www.classes.CustTV
        android:id="@+id/message_other_text_messageText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bubblechat_left_blue"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/message_other_txt_time"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/messagePlaceholder"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorBlack"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
        app:fontFace="@string/opensans_regular" />

    <com.test.www.classes.CustTV
        android:id="@+id/message_other_txt_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/message_other_text_messageText"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="@string/numberPlaceholder"
        android:textColor="@color/miBlack"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_smaller"
        app:fontFace="@string/opensans_regular" />

</RelativeLayout>
```